# Can I list down the Values of an Enum without using FormFlow?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have an enum

```
public enum SupportedProducts{
    Prod1,Prod2,Prod3 //..and so on
}
```

I have tried listing this using a easily `FormFlow`. However, this is the only question that I have to prompt. So I dont think I dont need to use a FormFlow for this.

Can I list down the Values of an Enum without using FormFlow? How do I handle the result of the options?.

Comment: Not sure if it helps you here, but you can get the names of all the items in an enum by using `Enum.GetNames` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PromptDialog.Choice` and pass in your enum as options. 
Sample code would be :

```
public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, ChoiceResumeAfter, (IEnumerable<SupportedProducts>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(SupportedProducts)), "Select a product");
    }

private async Task ChoiceResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SupportedProducts> result)
    {
        var response = await result;
        await context.PostAsync($"You chose {response.ToString()}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

So here, when the user selects an option, `ChoiseResumeAfter` method would be called and the user selected option would be passed to it.

Sample demo: 
[image]